# Stable, Hash Based Symmetrical Difference

Tags: algorithms, difference, unions

A lot of thought went into the implementation of the set algorithms in LINQ: `Distinct`, `Except`, `Intersect` and `Union`. They guarantee that the items are returned in the same order that they appear in before calling the method. So, these two expressions return the items in the same order:

```
var authors1 = books.Select(b => b.Author).OrderBy(a => a).Distinct();
var authors2 = books.Select(b => b.Author).Distinct().OrderBy(a => a);
```

The implementation of `Distinct` would look something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<T>();
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        if (set.Add(item))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation of `Except` would look like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Except<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source1, IEnumerable<T> source2)
{
    HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<T>(source2);
    foreach (T item in source1)
    {
        if (set.Add(item))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation of `Intersect` would look something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Intersect<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source1, IEnumerable<T> source2)
{
    HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<T>(source2);
    HashSet<T> found = new HashSet<T>();
    foreach (T item in source1)
    {
        if (set.Contains(item) && found.Add(item))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

I added a second set to remove duplicates from the list.

Finally, `Union` is a little more complex, but basically the same thing:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Union<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source1, IEnumerable<T> source2)
{
    HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<T>();
    foreach (T item in source1)
    {
        if (set.Add(item))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
    foreach (T item in source2)
    {
        if (set.Add(item))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

So, the only operation not supported by LINQ is symmetrical difference or `SymmetricExcept`. I have been playing around with creating a "stable" version of this algorithm and out of pure curiosity am wondering if there is a better implementation. The most straight-forward implementation is to just call `Except` twice:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SymmetricExcept<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source1, IEnumerable<T> source2)
{
    var except1 = source1.Except(source2);
    var except2 = source2.Except(source1);
    return except1.Concat(except2);
}
```

Although, this requires going through both lists twice. So I wrote a version that only requires going through the second list twice:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SymmetricExcept<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source1, IEnumerable<T> source2)
{
    HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<T>(source2);
    HashSet<T> found = new HashSet<T>();
    foreach (T item in source1)
    {
        if (!set.Contains(item) && found.Add(item))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
    foreach (T item in source2)
    {
        if (found.Add(item))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't verified the correctness of these algorithms. There is some ambiguity about how LINQ handles duplicates. I am curious if there is a more efficient way to do `SymmetricExcept`, something better than `O(m + 2n)`.

Comment: You spend a lot of time on "items returned in the same order" at the top of your question.  Is that important?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, that's what stable means when referring to algorithms.

Comment: OK, I understand.  I've only heard that term used with sorting algorithms, to describe the behavior of sorts when the comparison keys are the same.

Comment: Well, there are hash sets that maintain insertion order. I think that ought to help, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah. It is a little odd referring to a set algorithm as "stable". That's why I put it in quotes. :-)

Comment: See http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference.

Comment: My understanding of BigO notation, is that only orders-of-magnitude really matter. Having said that I don't believe it's possible to reduce `2n`. Intersect is O(2n) and SymmetricExcept needs the extra step of `m`.